# Best practice for formatting a string which needs to be send via TCP/IP

Tags: c#, c++, tcp

I have a couple of parameters, which need to be sent to a client app via TCP/IP.

For example:

```
//inside C++ program
int Temp = 10;
int maxTemp = 100; 
float Pressure = 2.3;
```

**Question:** What is the best practice to format a string? I need to make sure that the whole string is received by the client and it should be easier at the client end to decode the string.

Basically, I want to know, ***what should be the format of the string***, which I am going to send?

**PS:** Client app is in C# and the sender's app is in Qt (C++).

Comment: Do you mean, XML or JSON?

Comment: A common way would be to format the payload using e.g. json (or protobuf, or xml, or some other off-the-shelf serialization mechanism). Then format each packet as `[start character]` / `length` / `payload` / `[checksum]` / `[end character]`, where components in square brackets may or may not be used.

Comment: My first rule is to avoid using string for storage, transmission or retreival. It is the 2nd worst type for processing. Only raw bytes are worse | My second rule is: Pick a fixed culture format and encoding to be used at all endpoints. XML does that for you automagically. I think JSON does too. Dealing with that is a big reason they exist and are used. | You do not want to run into Encoding (https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) or culture missmatches

Comment: @duDE: I have the parameter values inside the C++ program as variables.

Comment: @Christopher: You mean that I need to format the parameters values in XML format? OR do I need to write the parameters to an XML file first?

Comment: @skm Most proper XML en- and decoder classes will write/read the culture format and encoding out of/into the XML file. It is put there the same way, we started putting it into HTML. | And for JSON, there is AFAIK only one defined culture and encoding. So all code can agree on that part.

Comment: Neither XML or JSON are formatted for efficient size. If this matters to you use a serialization library like _cereal_ that's available in both C++ and C# and send your data in binary.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty subjective, but if it will always be as simple as described, then: keep it simple:

ASCII, space delimited, invariant (culture-independent) format integers in their fully expanded form (no E etc), CR as the end sentinel, so:

```
10 100 2
```

(with a CR at the end)  This scales to any number of records, and will be easy to decode from just about any platform.

If it gets more nuanced: use a serializer built for the job, and just share details of what serialization format you are using.

Comment: But I want to put the Parameters name (e.g. T, P, mT) also in the string.

Comment: @skm Check it out how to with parameter names added.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII, of the form `paramName paramValue`, space delimited, culture-independent format and use integers in their full form (no E notation) and a carriage return at the end, for example: `T 10 P 100 mT 2` with CR at the end. In the other side, you can simply split the string by white spaces and note that even indices are parameters and odds indices are parameter values. Note that for every even parameter name index `i` then `i+1` is its corresponding odd index parameter value. Also mind the CR at the end.